# Get JSONObject by ID from another JSONObject - Android

Tags: android, json

I have a little issue with parsing JSON String which I get from a web server. So my JSON looks something like this :

```
{
 ..........
"statistics":{
              "660":{
                       "param_id":660,
                       "cat_id":2,
                       "param_title":"Number",
                       "param_value":"26",
                       "value_type":"singleline",
                       "elem_order":"1"}

            ,
              "662":{
                       "param_id":662,
                       "cat_id":2,
                       "param_title":"Name",
                       "param_value":"Dani",
                       "value_type":"singleline",
                       "elem_order":"2"
                    }
                    // --||--
           }
}
```

So I get a JSONObject `statisics` and I want to get JSONObjects from `statistics`, but the problem is that their name is different everytime.So I can't just do `json.getJSONObject("660");`. So any suggestions how can I do that?

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669730/java-representation-of-json-object/7669794#7669794

Comment: That looks good actually,but I can't say that my JSONObject names will start from 0 everytime.

Comment: Well it will give you dynamically, its not important that your JSONObject should have to be 0 everytime, just try it.

Comment: You just have to get "statistics" in a JSONObject and then a for loop upto jsonobj.length().

Comment: It's throwin me an exception that I don't have JSONObject with name 0.

Comment: Can you show me your code and complete JSON???? you can use pastebin for that...

Comment: So, here is the link of my JSON code : http://pastebin.com/rqsNGXBG  . It's still just a piece of it, because LogCat can't store my whole JSON. And the code I'm using is here : http://pastebin.com/L8ZahTVX . So actually I almost fix that, but the problem which I have now is : I get only one JSONObject from "sttaistics". Example : I get only `660` like `stats.length()` times. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
if(jsonObj.has("statistics")){
   Iterator<Object> keys = stats.keys();
   while(keys.hasNext()){

     String key = (String) keys.next();
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
     obj = stats.getJSONObject(key);
     // get JSON 

  }// end while

}//end if
```

Comment: It's an `JSONObject` : `JSONObject stats = jsonObj.optJSONObject("statistics");`

Answer (score 5):

use `JSONObject.keys()` to get key iterator, then `getJsonObject( key)` to get object.

Comment: Can you be more specific how can I use keys() ?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code-

```
JSONArray nameArray = statisics.names();
JSONArray valArray = statisics.toJSONArray(nameArray);
```

where names() method returns array of names and it is stored in nameArray and valArray contains array of values corresponding to valArray.

You can iterate using for loop over these array to get values.

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
JSONObject jsonOnb = json.getJSONObject("statistics") ;
JSONObject pagesObj = jsonOnb.getJSONObject(jsonOnb.names().getString(0));          

   Log.i("pageid", "pageid= " +pagesObj.get("param_id"));                  
   Log.i("title", "title= " +pagesObj.get("cat_id"));     
     ..............
```