# Java JSON editor / visualizer

Tags: java, json

I wrote an application that takes a JSON file as configuration.  Up to this point, I wrote the JSON config by hand.  However, now I want to allow other users who are not familiar with JSON format to make their own configurations.  There's only 3 types of objects that the configuration needs to store, but the user should be allowed to add multiple copies of these objects.  I want to write a configuration application where the user can press a button such as "Add Type A" and an object of type A is populated with default values and visualized so that the user can select properties and edit them.  I know how to write an application that does this, but I feel like I'm re-inventing the wheel.  Does anyone know of an open-source Java library that I can use inside my config application to handle visualization and editing a JSON file?  If I'm approaching this from completely the wrong direction, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to say "don't fear to reinvent the wheel". 
But the fact is that there a bunch solutions available :

[How do I convert an object to JSON representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145506/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-json-representation) (and vice-versa)
[Java representation of JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669730/java-representation-of-json-object)
[Javascript to Java using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792315/javascript-to-java-using-json/)

among them, [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) looks fine.

For my personal experience, [Yaml](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/YAML) turned out to be an appropriate solution.

Comment: GSON works very well for conversion and has a very clean implementation (just function calls).

Comment: I'm currently using GSON and it works great.  But I'm interested more in how the JSON file is visualized and edited by people without a software background.  I thought maybe there would be a visual editor based on a grammar that allows one to easily add / edit nodes in the JSON tree.  There's an online editor such as this: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/, but that's really just a small step beyond notepad text editor.  Would be nice if there was a way to add some auto-checking and auto-populating of parameters with default values.